# How can i create 6 <div> in php and arrange in a div wrapper?

Tags: php

I want to create 6 `<div>` in php by a loop with size of 200x200 px and arrange these 6 div in 3 `rows` and 2 `columns` inside a  `div wrapper`.
Thanks in advance

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <?php
  $i = 1;
 for ( $i=1 ; $i<=6; $i++){
   div1    div2
   div3    div4
   div5    div6
  }
  ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: use css to control the layout would be the easiest method

Comment: first i want create the 6 div in php and the using css,how can i create and put it side by side in 2 columns?

Answer (score 1):

The generating of the divs is the easy bit - use the `clear` property in css and assign it using the `nth-child` syntax like so:

```
<?php
    echo "<div class='wrapper'>";
    for( $i=0; $i < 6; $i++ ) echo "<div>$i</div>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

To see the wrapper background colour it needs a height -the `2n+1` ~ this is defined in the css specification so you need only use it like it is. Have a look on `css-tricks.com` etc for use of `nth-child`, `nth-of-type(odd)` etc

```
<style>
    .wrapper{
        background:blue!important;
        display:block;
        width:80%;
        min-height:calc( 600px + 7rem );
        float:none;
        clear:both;
        margin:1rem auto;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        border:2px solid black;
        border-radius:1rem;

    }
    .wrapper div{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid black;
        float:left;
        margin:1rem;
        display:block;
        background:whitesmoke;
    }
    .wrapper div:nth-child(2n+1){
        clear:left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it is exactly what i wanted,but 2 question, the 'n' parameter where have you defined? and second in #wrapper i set background-color but it  doesn't affect.

Comment: Thanks,the reason that i post this question is this that ,i want call a custom   php function that after take data from mysql and make as a pakage(title,image,description) put it  in a 'div'(it is like this sample:http://www.marcorpsa.com/ee/t1500.html) so  arrange the packages in 2 columns side by side as the program that you wrote,but because i cannot solve it,please let me know that do i post it as a new question?You know and can solve it.

Comment: Rather than using a static loop ( as in the code above ) use a loop based on the database recordset and add the necessary content to each of the divs ( children of `.wrapper` )

Comment: RamRaider,thanks,i have posted my main question,and appreciate you that have a look on it, if you see that i have explain completely by my codes ;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065986/call-a-php-custom-function-and-arrange-its-output-in-a-div /